# "or" operator in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very simple question, but would appreciate advice!

I am trying to run the following dplyr operation to remove rows for 3 states from a dataset containing data by state.

```
new_data <- old_data %>% filter(state!="NC", state!="AL", state!="AR")
```

The above command works. But, I am wondering if there is a way to remove the 3 states more simply, without retyping the `state!=` bit three times.

For example, maybe I could do something like:

```
new_data <- old_data %>% filter(state!= ("NC" |"AL" |"AR"))
```

However, this did not work. Your advice appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can try `... !(state %in% c("NC", "AL", "AR"))`

Comment: @markus Thanks! That worked for me!